# Managing Layout with soft input keyboard android

Tags: android, android-edittext, android-softkeyboard

I have an edit text located at the bottom of the screen.when edit text is focused i want to move only edit text along with soft input keyboard leaving remaining views position unchanged. window soft input mode resize and adjust doesn't work for situation because both affects other views.I wanr only my edit text alone tobe repositioned above softkeyboard  .

Note:The above said behaviour is done in facebook commentbox android

Comment: just try to use  android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden" in your activity in manifiest

Comment: that will hide my keyboard itself

Comment: android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan" use this one

Comment: that moves my whole layout above soft input keyboard. I want only focused edit text to move above keyboard without changing other view position